# Переключение Switch

Tags: android

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на Switch, он не переключался, но нажатие воспринималось им? Так как по нажатию назначен диалог

Comment: Что за переключатель такой, который не переключает, а диалоги вызывает, другие контролы для этого есть.

Comment: Если вам нужен `Switch`, который не переключается, то используйте вместо этого кнопку с фоном от свича.

Answer (score 1):

Просто сделайте переключатель неактивным и повесьте на него слушатель нажатий

```
switch.setEnabled(false);
switch.setOnClickListener(...);
```

Comment: А если я использую тот же самый onClick в разметке, то работать, получается, не будет?

Comment: Тогда просто уберите вторую строку из ответа.

Comment: Если убрать, то при нажатии на переключатель ничего не происходит

Comment: Тогда оставьте...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Шредингера

Comment: Если оставить, то почему-то тоже ничего не происходит, он просто становится неактивным